# Get current user's email address in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server

I would like to know the email address of the user (assuming she's in a typical Windows office network). This is in a C# application. Perhaps something to the effect of

```
CurrentUser.EmailAddress;
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Are you extending exchange server through some kind of API?  Is this a standalone application that connects to exchange and tries to find out when the "certain condition" is met?  You're not giving us much to work with here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP is talking about AD. However, Calv1n, you should probably clarify your question by editing it, or the community is likely to close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're behind a Windows domain, you could always grab their email address out of Active Directory.

See Javier G. Lozano's example in his tutorial, "[Querying Active Directory for User Emails](http://lozanotek.com/blog/articles/149.aspx)".

Answer (score 141):

Reference `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`, then

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
return UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress;
```

See .NET docs [UserPrincipal.Current](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.current) and [UserPrincipal.EmailAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.emailaddress).

---

Or with a timeout:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress);
if (task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
    return task.Result;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Much, much simpler than the linked article.

Comment: UserPrincipal.Current is very slow on my non-domain computer. Seems like a timeout of around 5 seconds before that property returns and I have yet not found a way to work around that.

Comment: Important: This is VERY slow if the user it not on a domain. One of those issues your customers will see and not you.

Comment: In addition - a non-domain computer receives an exception of "FileNotFound".

Comment: UserPrincipal.Current does not work on .NET, it throws PlatformNotSupportedException even on Windows OS. It only works on .NET Framework; see documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.current?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

```
// Simply by using UserPrincipal
// Include the namespace - System.DirectoryServices

using DS = System.DirectoryServices;
string CurrUsrEMail = string.Empty;
CurrUsrEMail = DS.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress;
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to use the Active Directory option and the other, most selected answer, did not work for me oddly enough.

I searched my code bank and found this which worked fine and with quick response:

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "[domain]",  dc=xx,dc=yyy"))
{
    UserPrincipal cp = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, Environment.UserName);
    userEmail = cp.EmailAddress;
}
```

Comment: That is LDAP, which is Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

No doubt many are fine using Directory Services (LDAP etc.), however for those not able (or willing) this might work as an alternative.

`PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook -Version 15.0.4797.1003`

```
using MSOutlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

...

```
private async Task<string> GetCurrentUserEmailAsync()
{
    var value = string.Empty;
    MSOutlook.Application outlook = new MSOutlook.Application();
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    MSOutlook.AddressEntry addrEntry =
        outlook.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
    if (addrEntry.Type == "EX")
    {
        MSOutlook.ExchangeUser currentUser =
            outlook.Session.CurrentUser.
            AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser();
        if (currentUser != null)
        {
            value = currentUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
        }
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(currentUser);
    }
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(addrEntry);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(outlook);
    return value;
}
```