# How to retrieve the default email (sender) of the default mail client?

Tags: windows, email, settings, default

When one selects a file in windows file explorer and right click, there is a context menu "Send To/Mail Recipient".  If you click it, your default mail client is launched. In the "From" field, you see your email address is filled by default.

My goal is to retrieve this email address using C# or some other language (silently, without invoking the web client).

Please give me some advice. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357123/get-current-users-email-address-in-net:

Comment: Thanks. I agree it"s a duplicate. However, either of the 2 answers does not work on my box.