# C# get all linked email acccounts

Tags: c#

Under Windows 11 there is the possibility to link more than one email account. (Settings->Account->Email)
Is there a possibility to get all those email addresses from the current user?

I would like to use those email addresses (no active directory) to check if the user has an Email address of a certain domain to enable or disable specific functionalities in my WPF (.NET Framework 4.8 or .NET6 doesn't matter) desktop application.

PS: `Environment.UserDomainName` is empty that is why I assume no active directory.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9688094/4828907 did not help as this email address is empty as well.

Best regards